# Disable axios request logging

Tags: node.js

Axios request output to console and log files some debug info. Any idea how to make `axios` silent?

[image]

For logging I'm using `winston`, tried to disable at all logging, but still see this output data.

PS: bearer token is out dated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my .env file I have line
`DEBUG = *`
If I remove that, don't see any more logs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically due to security issues you would have to tolerate:

```sh
[2022-03-23T12:06:17.789Z]  "GET /" "axios/0.26.1"
```

You would also need to treat the promise, either with `.catch`, `await-to-js` or wrap *axios* in a `try` block

**try block**

```js
let data;

try {
  data = await axios.get('http://example.com');
} catch (e) {
  e = !e; // do nothing with the error
}
```

**await-to-js**

```js
    const { to } = require('await-to-js');
    let E;
    
    function error(msg) {
        console.error(msg);
        
    }
    
    [E, html.to] = await to(axios.get('http://example.com'));
    if (E) E=!E; // do nothing with the error
```